# What ports should I use for Android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, port

I am currently creating an Android application. The application will be communicating with a server and also other Android devices running the same application. The server uses PHP with a MySQL database.

Is there a convention for what ports to use in Android?

Is it a good idea to hard code what ports to use or should they be different every time?

Comment: first of all let us know. on which language your server is running e.g php, asp.net etc?

Comment: The server uses PHP with a MySQL database. I've edited the question.

Comment: Keep in mind that a mobile network is unlikely to permit *incoming* connections.  So unless you are making an app for wifi, your program is probably only going to make *outgoing* connections, and can simply use whatever arbitrary source port the network stack provides.  The port assignment on your server would be unlikely to depend on the choice of Android on the client side.  So only if you are using wifi for peer-to-peer traffic is there really a need to make a decision here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no convention for using ports.

You may hardcode your ports (and I really suggest doing that, because it makes it a whole lot easier to code and manage).

It is however considered good practice to not interfere with ports for existing applications, HTTP (port 80) for example. Just pick an unused or rarely used port from [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

Comment: It should be noticed though, that some companies or ISPs block a lot of ports. So in some cases it might be even a "good" choice (compatibility wise) to use a default port like 443 or 80. (Just be aware that you would have a problem, if you wanted to add a webserver later on.)